# Why is the Google Play Store showing wrong app sizes?

Tags: google-play-store, android-11, oneplus-6

Since recently, the Google Play Store is showing different app sizes when downloading updates. The displayed size of the update is X but the downloading size (of the se update) is slightly greater than X.

For example (see attached screenshots):

- Messenger (FB): 44 MB -- 25% of 46 MB
- Microsoft Teams: 37 MB -- 29% of 39.01 MB
- Spotify: 34 MB -- 32% of 36.10 MB
- Uber: 49 MB -- 22% of 51.00 MB
- etc., etc., for every other update

Is this a recent bug in the Google Play updater?

Or might it be an indication that I have a virus or spyware installed on my phone?

> [image: Uber update size wrong].[image: Spotify update size wrong].[image: Microsoft Teams update size wrong]

Some more examples, comparing the size in MiB to the size in MB, as @Robert suggested in his answer:

> [image: comparison with MiB vs MB]

My main question is: Does anyone else has this issue on their Android phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Play Store seems to use MiB (1KiB = 1024 bytes) but displays like Windows "MB" as unit. The download size seems to be measured in MB (1KB = 1000 bytes).

```
44 MiB = 45,056 KiB = 46,137,344 bytes = 46,137 KB = 46 MB
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert! It would be comforting if that was the cause. But for some reason the numbers do not match. For some apps it's bigger, for other apps it's smaller. I've added a new table in the question.

Comment: @SorinPostelnicu If you add the assumption that the number in the first column is not exact but rounded then it would match. So don't start with the first column, use the last column instead and multiply it's value by 1,000,000 and then divide it by 1,048,576 and you should get the value of the left column before it had been rounded.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert ! Indeed, that matches perfectly!